# Return the last updated record if textbox is null / C# & SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server

In my web application I have page contains optional textboxes, the problem is if user doesn't enter all the textboxes, it will retrieve null value and I want to retrieve the last updated record, if the text box is null

```
<h4> Name:<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox> </h4>
<h4> Tel.No:<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></h4>
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Save" onclick="Button1_Click" Height="24px" Width="69px" />
```

Code behind:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=OSAMA-PC\X3;Initial Catalog=BiomedicalSample;Integrated Security=True");
    con.Open();

    SqlDataAdapter sda1 = new SqlDataAdapter("Update Site SET Name=ISNULL('"+TextBox1+ "',Name) , TelNo=ISNULL('" + TextBox2 + "',TelNo) WHERE IDd=23 ", con);

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    sda1.Fill(dt);

    sda1.SelectCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
}
```

Comment: TextBox1.Text (just TextBox1 is a reference to the control not to its content)

Comment: Most important: use sql parameteres instead of string concatenation to pass parameters. Otherwise you are vulnerable to sql injection and other issues.

Comment: I forget this point , but still the same problem

Comment: Note that ISNULL('"+TextBox1+ "',Name) will always returns the first expression because '' (empty string) is always not null. Please clarify your question, it is not fully clear what you want to achieve.

Comment: if the user enter the name and leave TelNo  box empty then click Save button  the footer of page will display the name  and  last updated TelNo Not 0 value , sorry for bad explaining because I am not good at English